# gfortran include path -- is there an alternative to passing multiple -I options?

Tags: gcc, path, include, fortran, gfortran

I have some Fortran code which uses included modules, and I am wondering what environment variables actually work to set the include path.

To test this out I've been using one of the NAG example codes.

This works:

```
$ gfortran e04ucfe.f90 -lnag_nag -I/opt/NAG/fll6a23dfl/nag_interface_blocks
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ export CPATH=/opt/NAG/fll6a23dfl/nag_interface_blocks
$ gfortran e04ucfe.f90 -lnag_nag
e04ucfe.f90:10.37:

       USE nag_library, ONLY : nag_wp
                                     1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'nag_library.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

However, the GCC/GFortran documentation states that:

> The gfortran compiler currently does not make use of any environment
>   variables to control its operation above and beyond those that affect
>   the operation of gcc.

(see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Environment-Variables.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables)

I've tried `ltrace`-ing the gfortran run and can see it looking at other environment variables (e.g. the regular `PATH`) but not `CPATH`.

I can work around this with this:

```
gfortran e04ucfe.f90 -lnag_nag `echo -I$CPATH | sed -e 's/:/ -I/'`
```

...but why is this necessary?  `CPATH` works fine with gcc, including for other languages than C/C++, so why doesn't this work with gfortran?
**Is there something I can successfully use to the same effect as CPATH for gcc with gfortran, to avoid having to pass multiple `-I` arguments?**

*Side note: `LIBRARY_PATH` works fine in a similar way, for replacing the `-L/path/to/libs` on the gfortran command-line.*

Comment: The docs state : "CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if specified with -I, but after any paths given with -I options on the command line. This environment variable is used regardless of which language is being preprocessed."

Comment: Actually, I fear that "being preprocessed" is the important point here.  I'll check if gfortran runs things through the preprocessor for includes, or if they're done some other way...

Comment: Yes, it works for the C PREprocessor, even when running on a Fortran source, not for the internal Fortran language stuff.

Comment: So I guess my question switches to "Is there an equivalent to the CPATH variable for gfortran, to avoid the need to pass -I arguments?"

Comment: Yeah, I don't think so either, I was wondering this too but couldn't find a solution. B.t.w. the CPATH trick works fine for ifort.

Comment: Actually I think, the best way around this would be to search for the modules inside the library but somehow this is also not possible (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know `gfortran` does not support this, which is quite annoying. But it is possible to work around it. If you name the following script `gfortran` and put it in a directory in your `$PATH` that is searched before the one with the real `gfortran` in it, then you will have the behavior you want, with `$CPATH` transparently being expanded into -I arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/gfortran $(for i in ${CPATH//:/ }; do echo -I"$i"; done) "$@"
```

Remember to mark it as executable. For example, if my `$PATH` is `/home/amaurea/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` and `gfortran` lives in `/usr/local/bin`, I would set it up as

```
$ cd /home/amaurea/local/bin
$ cat <<HERE > gfortran
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gfortran $(for i in ${CPATH//:/ }; do echo -I"$i"; done) "$@"
HERE
$ chmod a+x gfortran
```

Alternatively you can formulate it as a shell alias, but that would be less flexible and will not work in as many situations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Makefiles, I got this to work using the `subst` command. This replaces the `:` with `-I` for each path in the file.

```
usr/bin/gfortran e04ucfe.f90 -lnag_nag -I${subst :, -I,$(CPATH)}
```